# Retrieve shipping price via webservice in Magento

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, magento, magento-1.7

I have created my own shipping module, but problem is that collectRates function is called when user comes to shipping method step and then these prices are just shown to user. But in my case I have to use webservice to get price, and there are some options user can choose in shipping method step screen, which will affect shipping price. Price itself is calculated on other server.

So how I can set shipping price via ajax in shipping method step?

Comment: Please clarify: you need to collect the selected options, then call the webservice via Ajax to get the price based on those parameters? And it should be interactive, as in, you want to attach a listener to changes on some of the parameters, so when the user changes those, you can fetch the new price? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, I need to update shipping price every time user changes those parameters.

Comment: I don't know Magento, so I won't answer. But it looks to me the simplest thing to do is that you:
1. Set an update function (that picks up the price from the web server) 2. Set a listener to the price parameters so that when they change, the update function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found working solution myself. I call shipping.save() JavaScript function to update shipping methods page, then collectRates (php) function in my own shipping module is called and everything works correctly.

```
shipping.save();
```